# List sibling pages widget, exclude current page

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, widgets

I successfully created a widget that displays sibling pages to the current page I'm on in the sidebar. Only thing is, I'm not capable of excluding the current page - can someone please assist here?
I'm still learning and can't handle more complex PHP yet

**Edit**: To avoid misunderstandings -

- Page

  - Subpage 1
  - Subpage 2
  - Subpage 3

I want Subpage 2 and 3 being displayed by the widget when I'm currently on Subpage 1.

**Edit:**
I forgot to post my codesnippet:

```
    <?php echo $before_widget; ?>             

                        <?php
                            global $wp_query;
                            if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
                                $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
                            } else {
                                $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
                            } ?>

                            <?php 
                                if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )): ?>
                                    <?php if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>
                                        <div id="submenu">
                                            <ul>
                                            <?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent" ); ?>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

   <?php echo $after_widget; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the `exclude` parameter, see [Codex: wp_list_pages - parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#Parameters).

So for example you do:

```
$self = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

and add:

```
&exclude=$self
```

to your `wp_list_pages` arguments.

Comment: yay - I knew it was that easy but I still have problems writing it without causing syntax mistakes. thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: My pleasure, I guess you've found the right place to ask things you're not sure about :) @okiedokey